# Eclipse: Difference between "Save Actions" and "Clean Up"

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse has the same settings under "Clean Up" and "Save Actions". What is the difference?

[image: Eclipse preferences dialog, highlighting "Clean Up" and "Save Actions"]

Answer (score 0):

"Save Actions" are performed every time you save a file, but "Clean Up" is only performed when you choose Source > Clean Up from the menu.